# parse Json in linux

Tags: json

I need to convert this data in linux command. Any one can help?

```
{"date":"2005\u5e7405\u670812\u65e5(\u6728) 02\u664216\u5206","quiz_no":"1469","body":"\u4e09\u56fd\u5fd7\u3092\u30e2\u30c1\u30fc\u30d5\u306b\u3057\u305f\u6a5f\u7a2e\u3002\u6b63\u3057\u3044\u6a5f\u7a2e\u540d\u306f\u3069\u308c\u304b\uff1f","choice":[{"c1":"CR\u4e09\u56fd\u904a\u622f","c2":"CR\u4e09\u56fd\u904a\u7fa9","c3":"CR\u4e09\u56fd\u6f14\u7fa9"}],"answer":"c2"}
```

Comment: Convert it into what exactly?

Comment: You can't convert a json object into a linux command.

Comment: Convert into a readable string. Like  "date:2012/11/19"

Comment: The json data is from a txt file. So I need to read the data and convert it and overwrite the txt file.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a tool like [underscore](https://github.com/ddopson/underscore-cli) (based on NodeJS) to prettify the output:

```
echo '{"date":"2005\u5e7405\u670812\u65e5(\u6728) 02\u664216\u5206","quiz_no":"1469","body":"\u4e09\u56fd\u5fd7\u3092\u30e2\u30c1\u30fc\u30d5\u306b\u3057\u305f\u6a5f\u7a2e\u3002\u6b63\u3057\u3044\u6a5f\u7a2e\u540d\u306f\u3069\u308c\u304b\uff1f","choice":[{"c1":"CR\u4e09\u56fd\u904a\u622f","c2":"CR\u4e09\u56fd\u904a\u7fa9","c3":"CR\u4e09\u56fd\u6f14\u7fa9"}],"answer":"c2"}'|underscore pretty

// Result:

{
  date: "2005年05月12日(木) 02時16分",
  quiz_no: "1469",
  body: "三国志をモチーフにした機種。正しい機種名はどれか？",
  choice: [{ c1: "CR三国遊戯", c2: "CR三国遊義", c3: "CR三国演義" }],
  answer: "c2"
}
```

Comment: That is all I need. I installed underscore cli.  following this tutorial http://nodejs.tchol.org/ . And install was completed.  I checked with this command  # npm -v   1.1.19. But when I do this # echo '[1, 2, 3, 4]' | underscore map 'value+1'
the result is -bash: underscore: command not found
Any one know why?

Comment: I reinstall it. it fix. thanks.

Comment: I reinstall it. It Fix. but unfortunatly after using the underscore command ( echo { ...... }|underscore pretty ) , the result is still unreadable  for example  ( date: ^[[32m"1997綛完8?~H24?・19?~B159?~F"^)

Comment: It seems you are using a terminal without color support. You could use `underscore print` instead of `underscore pretty` to print it without colors (...or use another terminal).

Comment: I tried to use underscore print, the result was still unreadable.  ("date": "2007綛完7?~\~H12?~Wエ... ) .

Comment: I think this is a UTF-encoding problem with your terminal.

Comment: I have tried something like
$ export LC_ALL=pt_PT.utf8 
$ export LANG="$LC_ALL"

or
$ export LC_ALL=C
$ export LANG=C

it doesn't work. any idea?

Comment: Hm sorry, I don't know much about the terminal encoding. I think with every modern linux distribution it should work out of box. Maybe you ask another question about this issue on [Serverfault](http://serverfault.com/)... good luck. Ah, when the answer above solved your question, please mark it with the checkmark as solved.